# Take an xml feed from the internet and put it in my assets

Tags: java, android, xml, feed, assets

Currently i am developping an android application and i'm using an xml feed that i take from the internet.the problem is when my phone doesn't have an internet connection, my application crashs. I would like to obtain my xml file and put it in the assets.

My question is : is it possible ? And if yes, what's the best solution to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Check for Network connection:**

   ```
       public static boolean isConnectedToInternet(Context context) {
       ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       if (connectivity != null)
       {
           NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
           if (info != null)
               for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                   if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                   {
                       return true;
                   }
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. **Download XML String**

   ```
     public String getXMLString(String url) {

       try
       {
           URL url1 = new URL(url);
           URLConnection tc = url1.openConnection();
           tc.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
           tc.setReadTimeout(timeout);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream())));
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line;
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
           {
               sb.append(line + "\n");
           }
           br.close();
           return sb.toString();
       } catch (Exception e)
       {
           Log.d("Error", "In XMLdownloading");
       }

       return null;
   }
   ```
3. **Save String to any directory in SD Card:**

   ```
      private void writeStringToTextFile(String s, String f) {

       File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
       dir.mkdirs();

       File file = new File(dir, f);
       try
       {
           FileOutputStream f1 = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
           PrintStream p = new PrintStream(f1);
           p.print(s);
           p.close();
           f1.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
       {
       } catch (IOException e)
       {
       }
       }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Writing an xml file or any file in `assets` folder at runtime is impossible. Folders or resources in `res` folder are **"read only"** but, you can write an XML file on your application's internal data folder.

Just use the `Context.openFileInput(String)` and `Context.openFileOutput(String, int)`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)

**Update 1**:

This question might come on your mind.

`"If I write an XML file on my app's data folder, how to parse it?"`

You can use `XMLPullParser` class to parse an XML File. Here's an example

```
XMLPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("my_XML_file.xml")));
```

Comment: i was using sax parser.will it be a problem? will i have to change my code to make it work or is there an other solution?

Comment: I have no experience on SAX Parser. I have looked an example for it. If you're using an `InputSource` object you can do this  `inputSource.setCharacterStream(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("my_XML_file.xml")))`

Answer (score 2):

Add this method to your activity:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

and in onCreate or before you load your feed check like this:

```
        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    Player.this,
                    "No active internet connection found.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
```